# Diferença entre std::map, std::unordered_map, std::flat_map, e qual delas escolher?

Tags: c++, desempenho, hashmap, map

Qual é a diferença entre as funções da biblioteca `map`, `unordered_map`, `flat_map`, e qual delas utilizar, por exemplo em quesito de performance?

Comment: Talvez seja útil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166675/boostflat-map-and-its-performance-compared-to-map-and-unordered-map

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Sim, tirou minha dúvida, só tinha esquecido de clicar no botão para aceitar a resposta, desculpe por isso, uma coisa sobre a biblioteca boost, as funções delas comparadas a biblioteca std são mais rápidas?

Comment: @cYeR não tem como afirmar de forma geral. Cada vez mais a Boost é desnecessária na maioria dos cenários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance é relativo. Performance em que? Em acesso? Em inserção? De que adianta ter performance se a estrutura não faz o que precisa?

Se precisa de um mapa com ordem definida não pode usar um [`unordered_map`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Se precisa do `flat_map` e só pode usar a biblioteca padrão, como mostra a pergunta, não tem como já que não está disponível nela. Em geral o pessoal usa a [implementação da Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html).

A estrutura de mapa ordenado tem uma performance muito boa em quase todas operações, mas um mapa não ordenado pode ser mais rápido na maioria dos casos, embora não tenha garantias boas e no pior caso (muito raro, quase impossível na prática) pode ser extremamente lento (permite até ataque de DOS).

A (*ordered*) [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) geralmente é implementada com uma [árvore de busca binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) e a `unordered_map` costuma ser uma [tabela de espalhamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

A `flat_map` costuma ser uma árvore implementada em cima de um *array*, o que impede certas garantias em algumas operações (pode ser lento inserir um novo elemento quando a estrutura está cheia, e também não diminui de tamanho automaticamente se for possível), porém permite alguns ganhos no acesso, podendo ter até mesmo a melhor performance possível dependendo de como precisa do dado e como ele está organizado. O acesso linear costuma ser ótimo. A inserção pode ter ganho se também for bem linear. Os ganhos não ocorrem em qualquer conjunto de dados, pode até ficar bem pior.

Enfim, essa estrutura é boa para casos muito raros onde se sabe que os dados são muito lineares, o que quase sempre permitiria o uso de outra estrutura, quem sabe até mesmo um `Vector`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).